# mysql date_format unable to parse 20-may-2013

Tags: mysql

using date_format as specified in the [doc from mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select date_format('20-May-2013', '%d-%b-%Y');
```

returns null, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a date using DATE_TIME(), but that function is meant to do the inverse - take a known formatted date and display it using a custom format.  What you probably want is the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
select str_to_date('20-May-2013', '%d-%b-%Y');
```